# Is it possible to view a remote database in heroku on my computer (using Induction)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, remote-access, induction

In my rails 4 application directory, I typed "heroku pg:credentials DATABASE" into terminal to get all the information about the database for my application which is deployed on heroku. Since I'd like to view the data inside my postgresql database, I tried inputting the information into Induction, but it ended up not responding and I was forced to enter the activity monitor and force quit. I followed the same procedure several more times all with the same result. Is my version of Induction faulty? Should I be using a different program to view my database? Or am I doing something wrong?

I'm new to rails, so thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not a rails-specific question, and basically it should work. If you provide more details maybe we can assist. I use the command-line postgress client to connect to my Heroku postgress DB all the time. Aside from that: I always have a read-only replica of my DB, and that's the DB instance I access: I don't want to mistakenly run a heavy query against my production DB, thereby locking tables or just loading the DB. Not to mention write something or delete something by mistake.

Comment: Try to be more concise, saying what you are trying, maybe with pictures, that way your question could be read and solved faster. Also people will be more likely to read your question.

Comment: @NitzanShaked, what do you type into terminal to view your postgres DB ? And what kind of details would it be helpful for me to provide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Heroku Postgres allows connections from outside Heroku's network. The credentials displayed from `heroku pg:credentials` will be all you need and should work. Maybe try using the official PGAdmin tool instead?